# Undefined variable in a child view

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

i have created a master layout and extending it to a child view this way:

master.blade.php (short version):

```
<body>
@section('content')
@foreach($articles as $article)
  {{ $article->title }}
@endforeach
@show
</body>
```

Then a child view called child.blade.php:

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')
  <p>Some static content</p>
@stop
```

However, when i am visiting a page with child.blade.php i am getting an error:

```
Undefined variable: articles (View: /app/views/master.blade.php)
```

Why am i getting this error? I don't have this variable in my child.blade.php, so i guess - child view inherits master's variables by default? But why? I didn't used `@parent`

Comment: it's `$articles` not `@articles`, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: ah, it's a typo, sorry. I had $articles, so that's not a problem.

Comment: well then the problem is that when you're rendering the child's view (I guess you're using a certain action in a controller that returns a `View::make('child')`) you are not passing `$articles` to the view. If you don't want that then you should consider changing your `master` view or use `isset($articles)` before looping through it. Blade templates indeed inherits, it's one of its great features. I suggest you change your layout.

Comment: Try in main.blade.php to channge @section('content') to @yield('content')
I'm not sure is this problem.

Comment: @dabadaba, isset($articles) did the trick. But, anyway, why it does inherit variables from a master view? I am kinda overwriting master section.

Comment: @Heihachi I think you should take to time to read again how the blade template system works... In your `child` view you're using `extend('master')`, that means your **inheriting** it. Aren't you familiar with the concept of *inheritance*? In most cases it goes along with the word *extend* (it's even the word used by UML). Again, I think you're getting blade wrong, read some more tutorials.

Comment: @dabadaba, yes it inherits everything even sections, but i have a variable inside that section and i am OVERWRITING that section in my child view, so why it throws me an error about $articles? It should not even know about that variable, because i am OVERWRITING that section from a master layout in my child layout.

Comment: @Heihachi try changing `@show` for `@stop` in your `master` view. If that doesn't work, try changing `@stop` for `@overwrite` in your child view

Comment: @Heihachi It inherits other 'blade' templates, it doesn't inherit controller's logic...

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is View Composer. This way you can share the data between several views without repeating yourself. In your case whenever your child.blade.php view will be rendered additional data you want to pass will be added.

Read more at docs: [View Composers](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers)

If you don't want to use View composer you need to pass the articles to your child.balde.php

Comment: Thanks, but i don't need $articles variable in child.blade.php it is inherited from a master layout.